# linux chmod not working with windows flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I have a dual boot ubuntu 12.04/win7 machine. I am trying to  compile the latest m0d_wsgi file using http://grok.zope.org/documentation/tutorial/installing-and-setting-up-grok-under-mod-wsgi/installing-and-configuring-mod-wsgi.

I was trying:

```
./configure mod_wsgi.c --with-python=f:/python/python.exe
```

but getting:

```
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

I was advised to perform a chmod 777 operation,for example:

sudo chmod 777 mod_wsgi.c

but I notice that the permissions do not change regardless of wether I use sudo or not.

Is this related to different filesystems ( windows vs linux ) ?

If so how can I change the permissions.

Thank you,

PS: I have tried:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python
```

The result is still:

```
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

also:

```
sudo chmod 777 ./configure
```

does not change the privileges

Comment: sudo chmod 777 ./configure

Comment: sorry but why are you using the path to python.exe of windows environment instead of your ubuntu python executable? install python on ubuntu and execute the ./configure from ubuntu giving it the python path of the ubuntu filesystem as reported in your link. If you understand that i didn't understood, try to better explain.

Comment: please see addendum

Comment: Why are you trying to compile mod_wsgi yourself? Ubuntu has a package for mod_wsgi, called `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

Comment: I am trying to set up a self contained usb stick ( which I already use to do my php work and which has xaamp portable on it ) to experiment with django. I generally work on windows boxes. since I was stuck on the windows side , I figured I would try to use linux to create the mod_wsgi I need. Thanks, Bill

Comment: add the output of `mount` your drive maybe loaded with the "noexec" mount option.